# Combining Data From Rows into Columns, Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, In column A, I have a lot of repeating typeId's, with different data in columns C/D. I would like to take any row that has a duplicate typeID, take the data in column C/D and move it to the next two available columns, and delete the duplicates. Essentially condense the rows into columns creating a little bit more formula-friendly workspace for later use.

If the MaterialID's can be placed in order from lowest-highest left-right, that would be preferable. But, not too worried about that.

I would do it by hand, but I am working with nearly 50,000 lines, and around 16,000 typeid's, so thank you to anyone who has a solution and saves me that pain.

[image: Current Workbook]

[image: Desired Results]

Comment: Question Clarification: What is the end goal?  You mention wanting to expand on the data through formulas.  What will those formulas do?  I think you're running into trouble pursuing this *particular* data structure.  Perhaps you need it in this format to be parsed by some external program, but it sounds like you want to do further analysis in Excel, and this structure will cause heartache. -- Are there more than one Activity Type?  Will there ever be? -- Are the material types guaranteed to be only a few?  Will that ever change?  --  I say "ever" on purpose.

Comment: The data in its original format is normalized, which is a rare gift in "found" sources. I don't know what particular formulas you would like to apply to the data (see clarifying question above).  Based on the column names, it looks as though your data has actually been extracted from a database.  Due to the multi-valued *nature of the data itself*, you should work with the  database. The database can do the work you need done, and still export a spreadsheet to use with the presumably more familiar Excel tools.

Comment: @HaakonDahl I lilke the "rare gift" words.

Comment: The data will be used to make calculations. It is for a video game known as Eve Online. Each Material will have a "price" pulled from a separate sheet using a API (sort of). The data you are seeing are InputMaterials required to build the Outputs. The types of materials are never going to change, but sadly their are about 200 different material inputs possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result duplicates the material ID in the columns. Do you really want that duplication?

Have you considered a pivot table instead, where the material IDs are in the headings? Super easy to do with just a few clicks, and you can reference the data with lookup formulas like Index/Match.

[image]

Comment: This answer produces a different result than that requested, which in this case I think is a Good Thing.  Note that in the OP's desired result, different types of material are listed in the same column.  This is difficult to do from the original dataset, and will only introduce other difficulties later on, based on the OP's stated desire to expand on the data with formulas.  This answer (Pivot Table) is for now the best with two alternatives -- Perfect World:write a query in the original database, or Hell World: Re-create an RDBMS using formulas in Excel.

Comment: The idea of a pivot table being used would make things easier and cleaner, as above mentioned. And while it could lead to problems in future, I think that be overcame with a few ugly methods.. Going to go test that now